# How I fix UseStore and Userouter can't use

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Code have a problem is
https://github.com/devjinx/cardline/blob/main/src/views/login.vue
if I delete this codes not show error can I help you
after run build have same this in codes

error I meet in terminal
[Terminal Output show error][1]

version in package.json is be in photo
[package.json][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBpxV.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzaJT.png

Comment: that error is correct, useStore is not exported by pinia - you are probably using pinia wrong, it exports (amongst other things) `defineStore` which you use to define your store. The convention is, that the you create a store module that exports a function called `useStore` which is the result of `defineStore` ... though, `useStore` is a convention, the function could just as easily be called `ralph` ... in my case, I have multiple stores, so my store modules export `useAuthStore` and `useSysStore` etc

Comment: also, what makes you  think `useRouter` is an issue?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question should enough info to not make it mandatory to navigate to external links. The question lacks clear problem statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank everyone so much I will to fix in next question about ask but thank everyone